# How to change div background-image with linear-gradient from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change div background-image with linear-gradient from Javascript
Please try to correct below codings:

```
<script>
function abc1(){
    var pos = document.getElementById("test");
    pos.style.background-image="linear-gradient(to right,  
    #85e085 0%,
    #85e085 90%,
    #ff9999 0%,
    #ff9999 10%);";
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="test" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  
    #85e085 0%,
    #85e085 50%,
    #ff9999 0%,
    #ff9999 50%); width:200px;">dsfhdh2346346</div>

<input type=button value="CHANGE" onClick="abc1();">
</body>
```

Comment: Try `pos.style.backgroundImage` - notice the camel casing, changing `background-image` to `backgroundImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
function abc1() {
    var pos = document.getElementById("test");
    pos.style.background="linear-gradient(to right, #85e085 90%, #ff9999 10%)";
}
```

```html
<div 
  id="test"
    style="background: linear-gradient(to right,  
    #85e085 50%,
    #ff9999 50%); width:200px;"
  >
    dsfhdh2346346
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="CHANGE" onClick="abc1()" />
```